# How to refresh a fragment Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a mobile application and this one has a `YoutubePlayerView` in a fragment. When the app load the fragment who has the `YoutubePlayerView` for first time, it works well, but ***when I move to other fragment and then back to the fragment the video can't be played***.

I think this happens ***because the fragment never goes***.

> **I would like to someone help me to reload the fragment or reload the**
>   `YoutubePlayerView`.

Here is method:

```
private void loadYoutubeVideo(){
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constant.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b){
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(NewPortApplication.getAppContext(), "Falló al inicializar el video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: video can't be played? Why? Any errors?

Comment: tu mel ne bhai. kam nai lagtu tare kai biju

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this in your Fragment

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        loadYoutubeVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: setUserVisibleHint is not suitable for that